# Why is android studio degrading the quality of images?

Tags: android, image

When i add an image tothe drawable folder and then add a resource to the Image
View in android,the quality of the image gets highly detoriated..
This is the original image https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTq0U.png
This is the image in app
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyx4n.jpg

Comment: **WILD GUESS**: You went on the cheap and put some low resolution pictures in the `drawable` folder. Then on a higher density device these are scaled **UP**, which pixellates them. You better go the other way: prepare some high res images and put them in the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder. On lower end devices, these will be scaled **DOWN** and the antialiasing will do its magic to preserve them nice. With some approximation. Better would be to follow **the standard route** and `prepare a set of images for each density`.

Comment: Please review: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

That has to do with android screen resolutions. You can try viewing the same image on a device with a different resolution and you may find the image clearer or more detoriorated. The best way to curb this is using proper image resolutions for each android screensize. Create folders for all screen sizes in your drawables directory and get specified image sizes for each of the screens to optimize the resolutions. You will find a guidelines [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)